# Outputting an image from an SQL BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upload, blob

I have a php file which stores an image in a BLOB in a Database. The uploading part works fine. However it won't display the image and I don't know why. Help appreciated.

Two files:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload an Image</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="image">File:</label>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form> 
<?php 

//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("up") or die(mysql_error());

//file stuff
$file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))  
    echo "Please select an image";

else {

    $image=mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $imageName=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $imageSize=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if(!$imageSize)
        echo "Thats not an image";
    else {

        //upload    
        $query="INSERT INTO store VALUES('','$imageName','$image')";
        $sendQuery=mysql_query($query);
        if(!$sendQuery)
            echo "This is embarressing. It didn't work";
        else {

            $lastid=mysql_insert_id();
            echo "Image was uploaded. <br>Your image:";
            echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid/>";   
        }
    }            
}     
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and get.php:

```
<?php 
//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("up") or die(mysql_error());

$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST(['id']));

$imageQuery="SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id;";
$sendImageQuery=mysql_query($imageQuery);
$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($sendImageQuery);

$image=$image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;  
?>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are storing images in a database?  Generally only the location of the image is stored in the db

Comment: How are you trying to display the image?  I assume you are doing this: `<img src="get.php?id=2"/>`, yes?  What do you see if you put that URL into your browser directly?

Comment: What does the schema of your `store` table look like?  I'm not sure if you are actually inserting it correctly.  I assume the 1st column is an AUTO_INCREMENT field, if so it should be `INSERT INTO store VALUES(NULL,'$imageName','$image')`

Comment: Quick note: I don't think it's a good idea to use `$lastid=mysql_insert_id();` to view (an/the) uploaded image, in case you either have a high-traffic website, or two people upload at approximately the same time.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Is that actually an issue?  I assumed `mysql_insert_id` would return the ID from the last query *you* ran, not the last query ran on the database (possibly by another user).

Comment: Have a look at the entire code `$lastid=mysql_insert_id(); echo "Image was uploaded. <br>Your image:"; echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid/>";` @RocketHazmat The operative word here being `"your"`.

Comment: @Fred - How not? The last id only applies to the last query that particular user ran.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: From MySQL's docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html): `The value of mysql_insert_id() is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients.`.  So, there's *no* issue with using `mysql_insert_id`.  Multiple people uploading at the same time will not break this :-)

Comment: Possible scenario: What if "Bob" for instance uploads a file at `3:00:00` with `id=10` then "Larry" uploads at `3:00:10` with `id=11` will both be able to see the file they uploaded, or will Bob see what Larry uploaded? @RocketHazmat `Edit:` If Bob decides to see what he uploaded 15 seconds after?

Comment: @Fred: No, Larry's last_id will still be 11, and Bob's will still be 10.

Comment: As per my `Edit (above): If Bob decides to see what he uploaded 15 seconds after?` wouldn't he not see the last id? <= being `11` That's the part that I seem to not be grasping. @PeteR

Comment: @Fred: Not at all - as Rocket's post above, it's per client.

Comment: Ok, thanks Pete and Rocket. Your explanations are well-noted and appreciated, cheers.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: If it's any consolation, I had exactly the same thoughts when I started using last_id. Thankfully, it doesn't work like that though... :)

Comment: Thankfully, otherwise it would surely post a huge problem. Definitely worth it for me to keep that one on file, if and when I decide to use it. Thanks again @PeteR :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP uploads, as stored in the `['tmp_name']` are TEMPORARY files, which are automatically deleted by PHP when the script ends/exits, unless you've taken measures to move it elsewhere. You'd need to have something more like

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... handle upload ...
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "/path/in/your/document/root/$id.jpg");
} else {
   die("Upload failed with error code: " . $_FILES['image']['error']);
}
```

first. Note the addition of the error check - NEVER assume that an upload succeeded.

Comment: He's storing the file in the database: `$image=mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));`